# Where are wordpress actions, filters & hooks stored?

Tags: wordpress

I need to know whether the are other paths to files in wordpress core where hooks (actions and filters) are stored besides /wp-includes/plugin.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actions and hooks are not stored, this is the whole beauty of them. You register a new action with `add_action()`, adding a function to the list of functions that will be executed with the declared action. Then, the action is executed with `do_action()`, anywhere you want, even in multiple places. That way, functions can be added to the action anywhere and actions can be executed anywhere... 
That said, you might actually be looking to find where some actions of WordPress are, indeed, getting executed, in order to understand why something is happening, and look into it, and maybe interfer by adding another function (with another `add_action` declaration). Maybe this  is what you are doing, but you have to be more explicit if you need help. Anyway, in this case, just launch a search in your WordPress folders on "do_action", possibly even "do_action('name_of_the_action_if_you_know_it"...

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in global $wp_filter variable.

This variable is an array of WP_HOOK objects. 
WP_HOOK class is defined in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php.

This class has the method this->apply_filters which executes the function in add_action() when do_action() is called.

The funtion is executed via call_user_func_array() php function.